# Difference between Android Battery Optimization and Samsung's Unmonitored Apps

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, battery

My app was put to deep sleep, just like force killed when Samsung ask to fix the battery drain apps, even my sticky backend service got killed. Looks like there is some way to bring user to the battery optimization feature to disable battery optimization for my app. Anyone know the difference between Samsung's unmonitored apps feature and this Android original battery optimization feature?

Comment: did u get any solution for this?